# Which ISO Image Should I Select to Install Debian 9 Stretch?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-installer

I would like to install Debian 9 Stretch on my laptop to replace this Neverware Cloudready OS. I am confused why there are three ISO images from the website.

https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/

Which should I choose? DVD1, DVD2, or DVD3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described on the page you linked to:

> Initially, you will only need to download and use the first image of a
>   set (labelled as debian-something-1 to be able to start the Debian
>   installer and set up Debian on your computer. If there are more images
>   available here (labelled debian-something-2, debian-something-3,
>   etc.), they contain the extra packages that can be installed on a
>   Debian system (as mentioned previously). They will not be bootable and
>   are entirely optional. If you have a fast Internet connection, you're
>   most likely better off installing any desired extra packages directly
>   from the Debian mirrors on the Internet instead of by using these
>   extra images.

That means you should use [debian-9.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso) to install `Debian`.  It's also a good idea to try running `Debian` in a virtual environment to test it before replacing your current OS.

Comment: Yes, although in most cases I'd recommend people get the [network install images](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst) instead of the full DVDs. No point downloading all those packages you're not going to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate your responses.It is now clear to me.